# Using the same keyboard shortcuts in every IDE/editor

Tags: ide

I want to configure each IDEs/editor I use to have exactly the same key shortcuts. By default each IDE/editor has slightly different set of key bindings even for common actions. For example "close current tab" is bound either to CTRL+W or CTRL+F4.

Is there already a set of config files out there (one for each IDE, editor, etc) with the same key binding configured?